# I am trying to download something from the software center and it wont download giving me this error

Tags: software-center

```
installArchives() failed: Selecting previously unselected package libnss3-1d:amd64.
(Reading database ... 
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'wbritish' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'thunderbird-locale-en-us' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'myspell-en-za' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'mythes-en-us' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'hyphen-en-us' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'thunderbird-locale-en' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'firefox-locale-en' is missing final newline
```

Comment: Oh, I feel your pain. I just encountered the same error after a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04.2. I had recovered my data from a backup and this bug appeared when trying to update or install applications from the ubuntu software center - such as chromium (weird, right?) In the end I reinstalled ubuntu again. The error did not appear again.

Answer (score 0):

one of these might help...

**Option one**

if you go to the website of the software you are trying to install, you can usually find the '.deb' file which is the file type that the software centre uses to install in ubuntu.

Sometimes, the software on the software centre doesn't seem to install correctly (I've had the same issue).

When this happens I usually just download the .deb from the software manufacturers website (if this is possible) and 'double-click' it (which launches the software centre and installs the software).

So, three steps:

1. go to website
2. download software.deb
3. double click software.deb and watch the software centre download it for you.

**Option Two**

another option is to find the package name of the software you are trying to install and from terminal 'ctrl+alt+t' you can type

```
sudo apt-get install packagename
```

where packagename is, hmmm, the package name :P (To do this you will need to be on an admin account and know the password).

**Option Three**

Third option, try running

```
sudo apt-get update
```

before running your install

Hope this helps!

p.s. sometimes the software centre looks like it isn't doing anything or just looks a bit buggy (just leave it alone for a while before you try to cancel anything).

Comment: I tried all of these steps and none of them worked :( im getting frustrated now

Comment: if you go [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1319791),  you'll see that he suggests this is an issue when the files become corrupted due to an error in an update or something similar...

They suggest that to fix it you need to run the script in the first comment.

I'd be wary with this though and back your system up...

Comment: again, go [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/328187/items-cannot-be-installed-or-removed-until-the-package-is-repaired-do-you-want) and you may be able to fix broken packages by running `sudo apt-get install -f`