# Items cannot be installed or removed until the package is repaired. Do you want to repair it now?

Tags: uninstall, ubuntu-restricted-extras

I installed `ubuntu-restricted-extras` manually (*after downloading its compressed packed and then using command*, not online).

After installing the same, whenever I open Ubuntu-Software-Center, a pop-up appears showing:

> "**Items cannot be installed or removed until the package catalog is repaired. Do you want to repair it now?**"

It is irritating me too much as it is preventing from downloading and installing other softwares.

Please, tell me how can I remove or uninstall `ubuntu-restricted-extras` because everything was fine before it and I really dont need such extras package.

Please

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and type the following command to fix the broken packages:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```